# Hangfire Fire and Forget job sometimes giving error "Does not contain a method with signature"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire

When I receive an API request I enqueue a job with Hangfire (Fire and forget).
At the beginning it works, but after a the first few jobs are handled, some of the following jobs give me the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type `Tcc.Web.Controllers.TruckingController` does not contain a method with signature `LaunchCalculationProcess(CalculationJob)`
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
```

Here I enqueue the job:

```
_jobClient.Enqueue(() => LaunchCalculationProcess(job));
```

And here is the method that should be executed:

```
 [NonAction]
 public async Task LaunchCalculationProcess(CalculationJob job)
 {...}
```

As said already, at the beginning it works, but then at some point it fails and put some jobs to the retry-queue and then after some retries is suddenly works again.

All the methods are in the same Controller/Class.

Comment: If you have multiple hangfire servers serving the same queue, ensure they are all updated with up to date dlls of your code. You can see what server processed the job in hangfire dashboard

Comment: Ok and how can I remove a server?

Comment: I noticed that once the first job is done, it creates another server. From that point on, I get this issue.

Comment: When you go to hangfire dashboard, how many servers are listed under servers tab? These dont change unless you stop the hangfire exe/service

Comment: There is one listed and as soon as the first job is done, there is a second one. But somehow the issue does not occur, when I use PostgreSQL or InMemory Storage

Comment: If that's the case then your hangfire is crashing and reatarting... look into what's going on there